# No data received (Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) when accessing goo.gl short URL

Tags: macos, nat

I have a strange problem. I cannot access a web via goo.gl short URL on any browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.2

The status bar will show "Waiting for goo.gl..." for 30 sec or so, then it will show the error below. No data received (Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
[image: Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE]

However, if I just replace `http://` with `https://` it will open the web just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with my ISP. They disable what they call "NAT" function and give me another IP address, then ask me to restart modem. Now everything is working fine.